Index out of range in UITableview while scrolling
I am implementing a nested UITableview that is having a UITableview which has another UITableview within the cell, both of UITableviews are have auto resize cell with dynamic data and header&footer as well. So the problem here i am facing is that when the data is large in innerTableview, the application getting crash, some times when i scroll upto two/three cells it works but then it crash. I have nested arrays through which i am assigning data to the tableview.
Below is approach that i am working with.
I have Two arrays and a UITableview within main/parent view controller.
@IBOutlet weak var bookingListTableview: UITableView!
var sectionArray = [["Member-One","Member-Two"],["Member-One","Member-Two","Member-Three"],["Member-One"],["Member-One","Member-Two","Member-Three","Member-four"],["Member-One","Member-Two"],["Member-One","Member-Two"]]
var sectionRowArray = [
                            [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-Two"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-Two","M1-Row-Three"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two","M2-Row-Three"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-One"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-One"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two"],["M3-Row-Three","M3-Row-four"],["M4-Row-Three","M4-Row-four"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-Two"],["M1-Row-one","M2-Row-Two","M3-Row-Three"]],
                            [["Row-One","Row-Two",],["Row-One","Row-Two"]]
                            ]

Then my UITableview delegate and datasource methods are as below.
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionArray?.results?.count ?? 0
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let revampCell = self.bookingListTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "revampTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RevampTableViewCell
revampCell.sectionArray = self.sectionArray[indexPath.section]
        revampCell.memberTestPackageArray = self.sectionRowArray[indexPath.section]
return revampCell

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }


And inside the RevampTableViewCell, I have two arrays and a UITableview as below,
@IBOutlet weak var bookingViewMembersTableview: UITableView!
var sectionArray = [String]()
    var memberTestPackageArray = [[String]]()

Then my Inner UITableview delegate and datasource methods are as below.
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionArray.count
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return memberTestPackageArray.count
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let bookingViewMemberCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookingViewMembersTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingViewMembersTableViewCell
        bookingViewMemberCell.testPackageNameLabel.text = memberTestPackageArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return bookingViewMemberCell
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = .white
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: -15, width: tableView.frame.size.width - 30, height: 30))
        label.font = R.font.poppinsSemiBold(size: 15)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1369999945, green: 0.3569999933, blue: 0.5569999814, alpha: 1)
        label.textColor = UIColor.hexString("#000000")
        label.text = sectionArray[section]
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        return headerView
    }

The above code that works well as excepted but the problem(crash) occurs when the data for the inner tableview is large(like multiple rows inside section).
Or in more simple way if I replace the sectionRowArray,
var sectionRowArray = [
                            [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-Two"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-Two","M1-Row-Three"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two","M2-Row-Three"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-One"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-One"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two"],["M3-Row-Three","M3-Row-four"],["M4-Row-Three","M4-Row-four"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-Two"],["M1-Row-one","M2-Row-Two","M3-Row-Three"]],
                            [["Row-One","Row-Two",],["Row-One","Row-Two"]]
                            ]

with the below array,
var sectionRowArray = [
                            [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-Two"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-Two","M1-Row-Three"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two","M2-Row-Three"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-One"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-One"],["M2-Row-One","M2-Row-Two"],["M3-Row-Three","M3-Row-four"],["M4-Row-Three","M4-Row-four"]],
                           [["M1-Row-One","M1-Row-Two","M1-Row-Three","M1-Row-Four","M1-Row-Five","M1-Row-Six","M1-Row-Seven","M1-Row-Eight","M1-Row-Nine","M1-Row-Ten"],["M1-Row-one","M2-Row-Two","M3-Row-Three","M1-Row-Four","M2-Row-Five","M1-Row-Six","M2-Row-Seven"]],
                            [["Row-One","Row-Two",],["Row-One","Row-Two"]]
                            ]

How can i solve this crash? I have been stuck in this problem for 3 days but couldn't find any working solution.
The above data is dummy data but the real data that i am fetching is also similar to it.

You need revampCell.bookingMembersTableview.reloadData() after revampCell.memberTestPackageArray = self.sectionRowArray[indexPath.section] or you could reload the tableview in a didSet on memberTestPackageArray

Hi Paul, I tried using revampCell.bookingMembersTableview.reloadData() but it is still crashing.
It is crashing at cellForRowAtIndexPath of inner UITableview and the crash is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

That means that the number of items in your array and the number of items you have reported via numberOfRowsInSection do not match.

but it is crashing with static data as well!
By replacing small array with the large array.

Your problem is in your numberOfRowsInSection in your inner table view.  You are returning memberTestPackageArray.count but this is (theoretically) the number of sections, not the number of rows in the section. You need to return memberTestPackageArray[indexPath.section].count
Having related arrays to drive your sections and rows is always a risky approach.  You would be much better off creating an appropriate structs and then having an array of those.
Something like
struct Booking {
    let bookingDetails:[BookingDetail]
}

struct BookingDetail {
    let memberName: String
    let bookingRows: [String]
}


Now you would have something like var bookings:[Booking] in your outer table view.
Its table view datasource methods would then be:
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.bookings.count
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let revampCell = self.bookingListTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "revampTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RevampTableViewCell
revampCell.booking = self.bookings[indexPath.section]
revampCell.bookingViewMembersTableview.reloadData()
return revampCell
}

And your inner table view cell would be
class RevampTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var bookingViewMembersTableview: UITableView!
    var booking: Booking
}

extension RevampTableViewCell: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return booking.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return booking[section].bookingRows.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let bookingViewMemberCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookingViewMembersTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTableViewCell
        bookingViewMemberCell.testPackageNameLabel.text = booking[indexPath.section].bookingRows[indexPath.row]
        return bookingViewMemberCell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = .white
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: -15, width: tableView.frame.size.width - 30, height: 30))
        label.font = R.font.poppinsSemiBold(size: 15)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1369999945, green: 0.3569999933, blue: 0.5569999814, alpha: 1)
        label.textColor = UIColor.hexString("#000000")
        label.text = booking[section]
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        return headerView
    }
}


ok but i have done it without any struct, i created to nested arrays in main UIViewcontroller then in a function i apped those array depanding on condition after that i passed them to the UITableview methods.
Inside cell as well i created two array according to main controller.
Is it possible to do it using the arrays only.
Or How can i append those main controller arrays in the struct?

You can do it with arrays, but you want to try and have only one array, otherwise things are almost guaranteed to get confused.  You can use a mutating func to allow the struct arrays to be mutated or you can use a class or an actor instead. The point is to have some structure rather than just nested arrays. It makes your code clearer and less error prone

Hey I updated my inner numberOfSection with the following code,
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
for aSection in memberTestPackageArray {
return aSection.count
}
return 1
}
And inside cellForRow also i did same like i ran a for loop as "aTestPackage in memberTestPackageArray "
And looks like it is working :)

Plus can you tell me how can i create a struct for the above case and then how can i append or assign the arrays in that struct?

A loop inside numberOfRowsInSection is pointless, you have to return the number of rows for the given section parameter.

Yes it is but after using that It is working without a "Index out of range" crash.

That for loop is returning on the first iteration, so you could just return memberTestPackageArray.first?.count ? 0, so I am sure it will break if you have different number of elements in the arrays. Take my advice and refactor with a single array using appropriate structs. You are just hacking on a mess

Yes i agree with you that it is becoming complex and can break. But i am also confused about making a single struct for those array and appending that with the data.

I don't see how that is any different to using arrays directly. Perhaps ask another question showing how you fetch the data and explain any problem you are having with it.

Sure Paul I will try to use single array by making struct :)
